# regex is failing for version numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

i have used below regex for allowing me to enter alphabet, number, special character and should not allow trailing and leading space for the entire word

Not allowed patterns  :

`(space)text(space)`,

`(space)this text is having trailing and leading space(space)`

for the above i am using this regex pattern `/^(?! )[A-Za-z0-9 ]*(?<! )$/` and it is failing for this entry - `v1.3`

```
 rules: [
          {
            required: true,
            pattern: /^(?! )[A-Za-z0-9 ]*(?<! )$/,
            message: 'Please enter valid version value',
          },
```

Could any one please suggest me how to pass the regex so that i can be able to enter the data with versions and at the same time looking to satisfy above conditions as well. I am using react JS

Thanks in advance

Comment: that's not valid javascript regex - at least not in all browsers

Comment: The `.` is causing it to fail, I think this will do the trick: `^(?! )[A-Za-z0-9\.]*(?<! )$`

Comment: @MattCarlotta your regex is failing for `#2.3`

Comment: "alphabet, number, special character" ... so a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and space is all your regex is allowing .. "`A-Za-z0-9 `" - there's no "special character" in that at all

Comment: @EnigmaState Then you'll need to add special characters: https://regex101.com/r/EhOY2s/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a negative lookahead for a leading space followed by any number of characters and a trailing space:

```
^(?! .* $)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EhOY2s/6)

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow for a `.` in your regex pattern for in between the spaces.

This regex should work

`^(?! )[A-Za-z0-9 \.]*(?<! )$`

I added the `\.` to allow for `.` characters.

[RegExr example](https://regexr.com/4q83t)